# Writing function for symbolic and numeric input

Tags: matlab, overloading, numerical-methods, symbolic-math

I am writing a (rather big) pure function, which shall accept numeric and symbolic input. The problem I am facing is (mostly) with conversion symbolic expressions to logical expression. E.g., When I have a expression like `syms x; assume( x, 'positive' );` and a test `if( x>0 ); ...`, then Matlab throws an error; Either:

```
    Conversion to logical from sym is not possible.
```

or

```
    Unable to prove 'x > 0' literally. Use 'isAlways' to test the statement mathematically.
```

depending on the context.

Up to now I solved this problem by rewriting all my `if`s to `if( isAlways(x>0) ); ...` and adding a function `isAlways` in a folder `@double`, so that Matlab uses this function when it encounters a `double`.

The downside of this approach is, that I would have to write a `isAlways` function for each other type too (`single`, `int8`, ... ) (and also functions `simplify`,...).

Another approach of mine was, to write a function `isAlways` in the global namespace, and call the builtin `isAlways` when I encounter a `sym`. But, `isAlways` does not seem to be a built in, since Matlab reports

```
    >> builtin('isAlways',sym(1));
    Error using builtin
    Cannot find builtin function 'isAlways'
```

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem in a more elegant way, or at least another way?

---

Edit: I don't want to change the code of my function much, in particular don't want to add checks like `switch class(x)`; case `sym`; ... case `double`;...`, but add "functionality" to Matlab such that it works out of the box for most functions.

Comment: if you assume than `x` is positive, then... it will be positive,.. why are you trying to check `x>0` ? this is useless it will always be true. `x` is not a numerical value in this case.

Comment: @obchardon Imagine a situation, where `x` is given by the user and not a-priori known.

Comment: Then it doesn't have to be a sym anymore? You could add a check if `x` is a sym; `if isa(x,'sym')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Matlab version approx R2018 I ended up defined a function `isAlways` in a folder `@double` etc.
2. Unfortunately, the behaviour changed around Matlab R2020. Now it is not possible anymore in a reliable way to add functions to classes. Thus, I now define a function `isAlways` in the global namespace, which gets called for each type which does not have an overload.
   This is not the perfect solution, but it works at least.